# Fetch request to http address from a https website

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, fetch-api

Is it some how possible to send a get request from a https website to a http address with fetch API.

```
fetch('http://103.82.8.194/Data/', { mode: 'no-cors' })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data =>
        console.log(data)
    );
```

Like is it some how possible send this request from https://rionislam.github.io ?

Comment: Why do you want it? It is not possible with javascript alone in a browser that others usually use. It seems that you need to create a proxy server that receives http requests. It is best to include the data on your website instead of requesting it.

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible to request http address from a https website **directly** because of the [Mixed Content Security Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content), it'll be blocked by the browser.

You can use a https proxy to do so, something like: https://some-proxy-url?url=http://103.82.8.194/Data/.

or just upgrade http server to https